# Setting up Seagate Goflex on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a [Seagate Goflex](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/products/external/external-hard-drive/) external hard drive. When I plug it in it has set up files for Mac and Windows, but I'm new to Ubuntu and do not know how to set it up on here. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Usually when you plug a new USB drive in Ubuntu it pop a new icon on your Desktop. This is the drive. Also you can see it in Places

Comment: how come when I make a new folder, take the usb out, then put it back in the folder is gone?

Comment: weird, try gparted (sudo aptitude install gparted) and see if you see your disk when it's plugged in

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need any additional software to use the drive normally - the 'setup' files are backup software and other things that are not essential for basic functionality.

If your hard drive was dismounted uncleanly, ubuntu will mount it read-only. You can either unmount the drive and force mount it, or boot into windows with the drive plugged in, and shut down windows to ensure the drive was dismounted properly (or eject the drive through the removable devices manager).